# Dynamically create two EditTexts and save values in model

Tags: android

I'm stuck on a problem where the user uses a button to create two new dynamical `EditTexts`.
One `EditText` represents Article, and other represents Weight.

Now...after filling let's say 6 `EditTexts`, or 3 rows who represent 3 Models.

It should store them in `List` of that `Model`, or `List<Model>`.
So the main problem where I'm stuck is the part where I need to save the Article and Weight in Model, and update if update happens on any `EditText`.

The model is like this:

```
public class Dispatch {
    private String Article;
    private String Weight;
    .
    .
    .getters and setters

}
```

[image: The view]

I have implemented `onTextChanged` where, after user input it validates the fields...but how to dynamically create Model, or update the same corresponding to it's field.

This is how I'm creating the article `EditText`

```
private EditText createArticle(){
        EditText et_article = new EditText(this.getContext());
        et_article.addTextChangedListener(this);
        return et_article;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
private void createArticle() {
    // create new 'Dispatch' item
    Dispatch dispatch = new Dispatch();
    EditText et_article = new EditText(this.getContext());
    // pass the 'Dispatch' item to text change listener, so that it can
    // updated accordingly
    et_article.addTextChangedListener(new TextChangeListener(dispatch));
    // add the same 'Dispatch' item to the list
    list.add(dispatch)
    return et_article;
}

private class TextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {
    private Dispatch dispatch;

    TextChangeListener(@NonNull Dispatch dispatch) {
        this.dispatch = dispatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // assign the value after verification
        dispatch.article = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how can I know am I updating article or weight? And what when I create 2 Dispatch models, and then update the first?

Comment: You can set another variable inside `TextChangeListener` which will check whether to update `dispatch.article` or `dispatch.weight` like `if(tag == 1) { dispatch.article = s.toString() } else { dispatch.weight = s.toString() }`